# Can't list input devices ffmpeg linux

Tags: ffmpeg

On windows I could do something like this to list input devices:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

On Linux I try doing something like this:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f <x11grab/avfoundation>
```

And I get an error (I have also tried the latest git build from [here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)):

```
ffmpeg version n4.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Unrecognized option 'list_devices'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

How can I list my input devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`avfoundation` is only available for Apple devices. `x11grab` is meant to capture X Window servers and does not have a list_devices option available.

Comment: Is there any way to list my devices then?

Comment: Which devices? Which interface?

Comment: I am just trying to list my input devices, eg. a microphone

Comment: Each input device is controlled by some specific interface. A microphone, on linux, will interface using pulseaudio, although there could be others. A webcam would usually interface using video4linux. x11grab usually captures the desktop GUI windows. avfoundation is Mac only. list_devices for dshow works on Windows because Windows has a unified interface for external media devices.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. I found a page in the docs that helped some more thanks to your explanation! https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Pulse Audio:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/Samples/AsyncDeviceList/

Example:
`pactl list sources`

Other alternatives using alsa:

```
/proc/asound/cards
/proc/asound/devices
```